# Precision-Recall Curve and Area under Precision-Recall Curve (AUC)

Tags: logistic, classification, model-evaluation, auc, precision-recall

I created model (**logistic regression**) and now trying to create **Precision-Recall plot** and calculate **area under Precision-Recall Plot**. I'd like to note that this model is **defective**:

```
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

Data can be downloaded here: [download](https://easyupload.io/i3xuwt)

The problem is that I am getting different results from different libraries.

**Manual calculations of AUC and library ROCR**:

```
data = read.csv("lr.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
predictions = data$predictions
actual = data$actual
  
library(ROCR)
predict_obj = prediction(predictions, actual)
prc = performance(predict_obj, "prec", "rec")
x = prc@x.values[[1]]
y = prc@y.values[[1]]

nans = is.nan(y)  
if (sum(nans) > 0) {
  y = y[!nans]
  x = x[!nans]
}

plot(prc, main = "ROCR library")  
auc_prc = sum(diff(x) * (head(y, -1) + tail(y, -1)) / 2)
auc_prc
```

gives me this plot and **AUC = 0.3630107**:

[image]

with cutoffs:

[image]

**library PRROC**:

```
library(PRROC)
pr_curve = pr.curve(scores.class0 = predictions[actual == 1],  scores.class1 = predictions[actual == 0], curve = T)
plot(pr_curve, main = "PRROC library")
```

gives me this plot and **AUC = 0.7160321**:

[image]

**library PerfMeas**:

```
library(PerfMeas)
obj = precision.at.all.recall.levels(predictions, actual)
plot(obj$recall, obj$precision, type = "l", main = "PerfMeas library")
AUPRC(list(precision.at.all.recall.levels(predictions, actual)), comp.precision = TRUE)
```

gives me this plot and **AUC = 0.6938177**:

[image]

**library DMwR** (as wrapper of ROCR):

```
library(DMwR)
PRcurve(predictions, actual, main = "DMwR library")
```

gives me this plot (without AUC):

[image]

**My question is: why plots are so different? Which graph should I choose and what is my AUC?**

This question is connected with my another question: [What is actually AUC (area under the curve)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/496263/what-is-actually-auc-area-under-the-curve)